# Allow www-data user to mount root as RW

Tags: linux, sudo

I am running a system that has the root partition (`/`) mounted as 'ro' (read-only) for most of the time. However, I need to make it so that the 'www-data' user can make it 'rw'.

To make it 'rw', I use the command `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. This works.

However, when a PHP script ('www-data' user) executes the same command, it fails.

I have created a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder with the following content:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And I can confirm that it works because I can execute the `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot` command in PHP. However, the `/bin/mount` command does not work. Do I need to do something else?

I will make the sudoers file more specific so only that particular command can be executed, but for now I am just trying to make it work.

Looking at the logs. After manually executing the command:

```
2020-10-22T19:37:19+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18582]:       pi : TTY=serial1 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
2020-10-22T19:37:20+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18582]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
2020-10-22T19:37:20+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
2020-10-22T19:37:20+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18582]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

After executing command via the PHP script:

```
2020-10-22T19:38:26+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18703]: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/www/web ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mount -vo remount,rw /
2020-10-22T19:38:27+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18703]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
2020-10-22T19:38:27+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 sudo[18703]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
2020-10-22T19:38:27+0000 d0-14-11-00-00-03 kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

### Solved

Solved using solution from here:

[Remount root file-system via PHP and apache2 doesn't work before execute mount via shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884896/remount-root-file-system-via-php-and-apache2-doesnt-work-before-execute-mount-v)

Comment: The presence of user `pi` in the first log excerpt suggest this is a Raspberry Pi or similar, but which Linux distribution are you using, and which version of it? It might be that the web server runs the PHP scripts chrooted, and so the `/` of the command executed by the PHP script is not the real root filesystem.

Comment: I am running Debian Buster (10) and apache2 webserver.

Comment: If I do an "ls /", I get the correct result, so I think that might not be the problem. Furthermore, if the filesystem is already RW, I can set it to RO (as it is by default in fstab), but not the other way around.

Comment: So much of that theory, then. Is it Raspbian 10, or "proper" Debian? There are some significant differences between the two.

Comment: @telcoM I have managed to find a solution after some more 'googling'. Essentially, the apache2.service has the 'PrivateTemp=true' option. After disabling that it works ok. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @CezChi would you please post that as an Answer, below? That way, future visitors can easily find the answer instead of reading through comments. Thank you!